# A circle with diameter $AC$ is intersected by a secant at points $B,D$. The secant and the diameter intersect at point $P$ outside the circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, problem-solving

> A circle with diameter $AC$ is intersected by a secant at points $B,D$. The secant and the diameter intersect at point $P$ outside the circle. Perpendiculars $AE$ and $CF$ are drawn at the secant. If $EB = 2$ and $BD = 6$, find $DF$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

Unfortunately I have no idea to start with this. A first idea is to find similar triangles, which I find a lot, but I cannot find a way on how to use the lengths of $EB$ and $BD$.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the center of the circle as $O$. Draw a perpendicular line from $O$ to the secant, and denote the point of intersection $Q$.

We can prove that $BQ = QD$. Moreover $EA // QO // FC$.

Since $AO = OC$ as radii, $EQ = QF$ by intercept theorem.

Now $FD = QF - QD = EQ - BQ = EB = 2$.

Comment: This is more simple, thanks.

Comment: I feel like the other one is equally as simple, if not simpler.

Comment: I find this easier to understand if you ask me.

Comment: Yes this solution is good. Shows outright that OQ bisects BD as well as EF.

Answer (score 3):

$\angle ADE = \angle DCF\Rightarrow \triangle AED \sim \triangle DFC $
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{AE}{DF} = \dfrac{AD}{DC} $$

$\angle ABE = \angle ACD\Rightarrow\triangle AEB \sim \triangle ADC $
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{AE}{EB} = \dfrac{AD}{DC} $$

$$\therefore DF=EB =2$$

Comment: Ohk , I was not been able to find out how to use the similar triangles so that I can use the known lengths too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the point of intersection of line FC with circle as M.
If we chase the angles we find BA=DM,AE=FM and angle BEA=DFM
So, BAE is congruent to DMF and DF=EB=2

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Remember to use LaTeX.